# Firebase Emulators missing tsconfig.json?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have a firebase project using Javascript (not TypeScript), but have started getting the error when trying to run a functions emulator

`$ firebase emulators:start --only functions`

> ⚠  functions: Cannot find module './tsconfig.json'
>
> ⚠  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.

What gives? Why would my javascript application suddenly start requiring a typescript configuration? What should this file contain?

I started getting this error when upgrading `firebase-tools` from v7.11.0 to v8.4.2.

I tried running `firebase init` on the project again thinking the new tools might set some missing configuration when I choose Javascript over Typescript, but it had no affect.

Comment: Please edit the question to show exactly what you did to set up the project, up to the point of running that command.

Comment: tsconfig might be related also to features like await/async , import/export etc

Comment: @DougStevenson The project is old, been working fine for ages. It looks like the breaking change was upgrading firebase tools from v7.11.0 to v8.4.2. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: If you have a bug report for the Firebase CLI, I suggest filing that on [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools).  Without seeing all the contents of a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), there's not much we can do but speculate.  Personally, I have no idea.

Comment: Yep, this issue is coming with latest version of Firebase libs. Good that someone posted it here - else I would have kept wondering what I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue with a similar setup. I created a file name tsconfig.json with the contents `{}` and was then given the real issue (await is only valid in async function).

I'm guessing there's something in the error handling that's trying to look at tsconfig.json when it shouldn't.